# QUdpSocket not receiving packets over wifi

Tags: windows, qt, sockets, networking

I am using QUdpSocket to receive UDP packets over WiFi. My program was running fine until
my system crashed. After that I am not able to receive UDP packets. I used Wireshark to ensure that packets are arriving on my system but my slot readData is not getting called. 
However I can receive packets when I send packets on localhost using QUdpSocket.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dont know why it happned but fixing my firewall with microsoft fix it tool and
using system restore solved my problem. =)